# FindFirstFile returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE when lpFileName is volume

Tags: c++, winapi

There is a short example:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(L"C:", &fd);
if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    wprintf(L"Err = %d\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}

do {
    std::wstring fullPath(fd.cFileName);
    wprintf(L"FullPath = %s\n", fullPath.c_str());
} while (FindNextFile(h, &fd));

FindClose(h);
```

I'm confused since

```
HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(L"C:", &fd); // OK

HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(L"E:", &fd); // INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(L"F:", &fd); // INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
```

But `E` and `F` are real, existing volumes.

I do so because I need all information from the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure which will be passed to the kernel mode.

Comment: I'm guessing you tried E:\  and that didn't work either? What does GetLastError return?

Comment: What exactly are you hoping for here? What should the function return for a volume?

Comment: Hello, @immibis ! Yes I tired it. GetLastError returns 2("The system cannot find the file specified.")

Comment: As the name implies, `FindFirstFile` enumerates **files**. `C:`, `E:`, and `F:` designate **volumes** (presumably). This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: At a guess, C: is NTFS and E: and F: are FAT.  In NTFS the root directory is located in the Master File Table like any other file, so it has the same sort of metadata, including attributes, timestamps, and a name.  In FAT the metadata for a file is stored in the parent directory, so by definition the root directory doesn't have any metadata.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be based on a misunderstanding. You say:

> I do not want to examine the files and directories in "E:*", I want to get information about this volume.

and

> I need all information from the WIN32_FIND_DATA structure.

Well, the find data information is meaningful for file and directory objects, but not for volume objects.

You'll need to use some other means to obtain volume information. Perhaps `GetVolumeInformation`, WMI, or maybe something else depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put `"E:\\*"` not only the volume. Or you want to find the volume entry? Also, it is good to clean `fd` structure `memset( &fd, 0, sizeof fd )`.

Comment: Just `"E:\\*"` will also do.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer.
But I do not want to examine the files and directories in "E:\\*", I want to get infromation about this volume.

Comment: @user3456796: information about the volume, or information about the volume's root directory?

Answer (score 0):

On my machine (Win7 x64) `FindFirstFile(L"C:", &fd)` returns -1 (`C:` is system disc), `GetLastError()` is 2 (i.e. "file not found").

I've checked how `FindFirstFile` is working. It converts winapi like path to nt path at some stage using [`RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U`](http://doxygen.reactos.org/d9/d6e/lib_2rtl_2path_8c_adf280bfe8b5d391fb6e60faed87e44d6.html) and then checks whether `PartName` is empty or not.

If it's empty it returns mentioned error code.

if it's a mask, it continues and enumerates entries that match: that's why `FindFirstFile(L"C:\\*.*", &fd)` returns valid handle. Thus if you need to enumerate all files in `C:` using form `C:\\*.*`.

In case if you need a volume information use special function [`GetVolumeInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993(v=vs.85).aspx).